# How do I prevent Visual Studio 2015 from launching a browser after publishing an asp.net application?

Tags: browser, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment, one-click-web-publishing

I am working on a site with a publishing profile that pushes the site to a remote host. After publishing I get a new browser window that navigates to the newly published site. This is ok in most circumstances but I am in a situation where I can't allow that last step to occur, I simply want to tell visual studio not to show me the website after publishing. I've checked all the publishing settings that I can find but haven't found any option to control this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does this information from Visual Studio 2013 still hold true for 2015?

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

I can't check it myself, but essentially it says that in the 'connection' tab of the deploy dialog,  the **Destination URL** setting isn't required. When Visual Studio finishes deploying the application, it automatically opens your default browser to this URL. If you don't want the browser to open automatically after deployment, leave this box blank.

Do you want to try that?

Comment: That was it, I had no idea that field controlled that feature. Thanks a ton!

Comment: This also holds true for Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 5):

Update for Visual Studio 2019:

In the "Publish" page, look for "Configuration". On the right side, click the Pencil Icon.

In the next dialog, open the "Connection" tab, and empty the field "Destination URL".

Comment: Came here because it looks like mine is not opening the destination url after publishing. Are you experiencing the same issue?